# Ehcache doen't flush to disk when process is killed

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I am using Springboot 2.1.3.RELEASE with Spring Cache and Ehcache. The default version for Ehcache in the Springboot parent pom is 2.10.6, i think. I'm using Cache to save all my expensive hive query results straight to the disk, and ehcache.xml looks like this:

```xml
<diskStore path="D:\ehcache"/> 
    <defaultCache name="default"
            maxElementsInMemory="1"
            eternal="true"
            diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
                  overflowToDisk="true"
                  diskPersistent="true"
            memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU">
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="myCache"></cache>
```

During development the application with IntelliJ, I notice the cache is lost time from to time, but sometimes it's fine. Even when I don't modify any code, the result could still be unpredictable. It took me two days of experiment and finally I noticed if I hit the `Exit` button instead of `Stop` (which I use my entire career as a Java developer), cache hasn't been lost, not even once. The challenge is though, when Intellij is running in Debug mode, there isn't `Exit` button. I did my research and found (can't remember where) that it's designed like this on purpose, the explanation being that when running in Run mode, the user application is wrapped with a certain wrapper and the latter is responsible for receiving the Exit request and acting upon it, but Debug mode doesn't have such wrapper, and the next thing possible to do, is to evaluate a System.exit(0), only when user application is suspended at a breakpoint.

My question is, since I don't care about performance, can I make ehcache to flush to disk every time an object is saved to it? so that it becomes Stop/Kill resistance? Though I'm new to Ehcache, I did a lot of search and can't find anything wrong in my config. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ehcache configuration, but the behavior you're looking for is called *write-through*.

Answer (score 1):

The Ehcache open source disk store will only be loaded on next startup if it was properly *closed*.

Any other exit, via application crash, kill or whatever will cause the disk store to be considered dirty and thus it will be dropped on next startup.

Ehcache offers an enterprise version which has a crash proof disk store, but as the name implies this is no longer a free offering.

See [the documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.7/tiering.html#disk-tier) for details. Note that the linked doc is for version 3, but the principles are the same.

Comment: Thanks. Your description fits my situation. Guess Ehcache non enterprise edition won't "write through" after all. The problem is, when developing an app in Debug mode with Intellij, there's no graceful Exit. The only button for that functionality is Stop, essentially kill the process. Bummer. Thanks alot!

Comment: Pressing CTRL+C in the Spring-Boot application console seems to invoke graceful application exit.